# Trying to transfer python package to offline computer but have too many dependencies to install

Tags: python, pip

I need to start python coding in an computer which is win 7 having python 3.6 installed and it's not allowed to access the internet. So I am trying to transfer python package to that computer by download from the win 10 computer that have access to the internet and having python 3.10 installed, and then use pip install in that computer. I manually check every package on PYPL to make sure it could be using on a python 3.6 system. Then I start to moving files but I got some problems here

Here is what I have done

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
pip download -d ～/packagesdir -r requirements.txt
```

And I got a list of python package like this

```
absl-py==1.0.0
cached-property==1.5.2
dataclasses==0.8
cffi==1.15.0
astroid==2.9.0
typed_ast==1.5.2
astunparse==1.6.3
async-generator==1.10
attrs==21.2.0
backcall==0.2.0
brotlipy==0.7.0
bleach==4.1.0
cachetools==4.2.4
```

and then I downloaded all of them and copy paste into another computer. I am typing this on my new computer

```
pip install --no-index --ignore-installed --find-links=packagesdir -r requirements.txt
```

and I got some problems here

```
Collecting zipp==3.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 149))
Collecting dask==2.13.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 150))
Collecting pytest==7.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 151))
Collecting nltk==3.6.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 152))
Collecting pendulum==2.1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 153))
Collecting moviepy==1.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 154))
Collecting six (from absl-py==1.0.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
Collecting pycparser (from cffi==1.15.0->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Collecting wheel<1.0,>=0.23.0 (from astunparse==1.6.3->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
Collecting chardet>=3.0.4 (from camelot-py==0.10.1->-r requirements.txt (line 14))
Collecting simplegeneric>0.8 (from ipython==5.7.0->-r requirements.txt (line 38))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement simplegeneric>0.8 (from ipython==5.7.0->-r requirements.txt (line 38)) (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for simplegeneric>0.8 (from ipython==5.7.0->-r requirements.txt (line 38))
```

So apparently for the first part of my code I didn't download the dependencies, is there a method to check and download all the dependencies on one-click rather than wait for problems pop up everytime and download one by one?

Comment: The online platform where you download packages must have the same (or very similar) OS and Python version. Install Python 3.6 instead of 3.10 and repeat the process. BTW your process is exactly right.

Comment: @phd ok thanks. It's just too annoying to install all dependencies one by one

Comment: `pip download` downloads all at once.